# Schedule a job in quartz with a set of triggers

Tags: java, generics, collections, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz 2.2 and I want to schedule a job with a set of triggers.
   I plan to use the following method.

```
void scheduleJobs(Map<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>> triggers, boolean replace)
```

My question is, how do I create a `Set` that takes in a class that extends `Trigger`?
`TriggerBuilder` returns only the `Trigger`, but I can't put the same in the set.
I searched the API but could not find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Issue resolved with the help of solution provided by Szpak. Thanks Szpak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way (probably not the cleanest one) in plain Java is to do the following:

```
    QuartzScheduler quartzScheduler = ...

    Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<>();
    triggers.add(new SimpleTriggerImpl());
    triggers.add(new CronTriggerImpl());

    Map<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>> triggersAndJobs = new HashMap<>();
    triggersAndJobs.put(new JobDetailImpl(), triggers);

    quartzScheduler.scheduleJobs(triggersAndJobs, false);
```

Or if you are not using Java 7:

```
    QuartzScheduler quartzScheduler = ...

    Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<Trigger>();
    triggers.add(new SimpleTriggerImpl());
    triggers.add(new CronTriggerImpl());

    Map<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>> triggersAndJobs = new HashMap<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>>();
    triggersAndJobs.put(new JobDetailImpl(), triggers);

    quartzScheduler.scheduleJobs(triggersAndJobs, false);
```

A shorter version with Guava:

```
    QuartzScheduler quartzScheduler = ...

    Set<? extends Trigger> set = Sets.newHashSet(new SimpleTriggerImpl(), new CronTriggerImpl());

    Map<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>> triggersAndJobs = Maps.newHashMap();
    triggersAndJobs.put(new JobDetailImpl(), set);

    quartzScheduler.scheduleJobs(triggersAndJobs, false);
```

**Update**. Using `TriggerBuilder` in fact doesn't change much. `TriggerBuilder.build()` returns a trigger instance which can be referenced just as `Trigger`.

```
    QuartzScheduler quartzScheduler = ...

    Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<Trigger>();

    Trigger trigger1 = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity(triggerKey("myTrigger", "myTriggerGroup"))
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInHours(1)
                    .repeatForever())
            .startAt(futureDate(10, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
            .build();
    triggers.add(trigger1);

    Trigger trigger2 = newTrigger() ...
    triggers.add(trigger2);

    Map<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>> triggersAndJobs = new HashMap<JobDetail, Set<? extends Trigger>>();
    triggersAndJobs.put(new JobDetailImpl(), triggers);

    quartzScheduler.scheduleJobs(triggersAndJobs, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to add few things. First, I use java 1.6. Second, I use TriggerBuilder to build the trigger.

Comment: @Aceghn, It doesn't change much. See updated answer.